# Problemas con índices y condiciones

Tags: python, tablas, celdas

tengo la siguiente tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi idea es en la columna Situacion llenar con la palabra alerta cada vez que la columna Color cambia de rojo a verde o de verde a rojo (y además que la celda de alerta tenga un color distinto para cada cambio).
La verdad no sé cómo hacerlo, pues me cuesta mucho trabajar con los índices para las posiciones.
Esto es todo lo que se me ocurrió hasta ahora:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Claramente hay errores, pero no los entiendo.

Lo que busco es algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar, por favor, lo agradecería muchísimo.

Muchas gracias!!!

Saludos!!!

Comment: El código va en formato texto y no en imagen.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lee todos los links.. aprende a usar el sitio, sobre todo si no queres que tu pregunta termine cerrada...

Comment: Gracias por los consejos @gbianchi... leeré lo que mencionas. Saludos!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes solucionarlo sin tanto for de manera mas limpia de la siguiente manera:

```
tabla['Situacion'] = np.where(tabla['Color'].shift(-1) == tabla['Color'], "-", "Alerta")
```

Debes incluir numpy.

Te dejo un screenshot full:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el codigo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tabla = pd.DataFrame()
tabla['Color']=['rojo','verde','rojo','verde','rojo','rojo','rojo','verde']

tabla['Situacion'] = np.where(tabla['Color'].shift(-1) == tabla['Color'], "-", "Alerta")
```

- [Comparar siguiente fila](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673209/pandas-compare-next-row)
- [Operador ternario en dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525270/pandas-ternary-conditional-operator-for-setting-a-value-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado por tu respuesta, pero creo que no es lo que necesito.
Lo que requiero es algo como lo siguiente:

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado por tu respuesta, pero creo que no es lo que necesito.
Lo que requiero es algo como lo que agregué en el post original.

De todas maneras voy a revisar el código que compartiste para ver si puedo entenderlo y luego aplicarlo a lo que necesito.

Saludos!!!

Comment: @Andres si esto no soluciona tu problema, porque lo pusiste como respuesta aceptada??? tu comentario dice que no lo soluciona....

Comment: gbianchi, estimado, no tenía en conocimiento eso de la respuesta aceptada. Pinche el símbolo pues me pareció que se refería a un "me gusta".
Lamento la confusión. Ahora que sé qué significa, tendré más cuidado en el futuro. Gracias!!!

Comment: Ejecuta el código con tus datos, básicamente sale alerta solo cuando existe cambio de estado respecto al registro anterior

Comment: SMN947, lo ejecuté con mis datos, y sí, es como dices. Ahora lo entendí. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.
Saludos!!!

Comment: @Andres no en el futuro. Ahora!.. .arreglalo ahora... no sirve como respuesta aceptada si no responde la pregunta...

Comment: Estimado, finalmente entendí lo que hace el código propuesto y, modificándolo un poco, es lo que estaba buscando. Así que finalmente es respuesta aceptada.
Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

Buscando info [aquí](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/01_table_oriented.html#min-tut-01-tableoriented) y la info de **shift** [aquí](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) conseguí hacer esto sin usar numpy, pero no sé si se consideraría adecuado o eficiente.

```
import pandas as pd
tabla = pd.DataFrame()

tabla['Color'] = ['rojo', 'rojo', 'verde', 'verde', 'rojo', 'verde', 'rojo', 'verde', 'rojo' ]
tabla['Cambio'] = ''

tabla['Cambio'].loc[ tabla['Color'].shift(1) != tabla['Color']] = 'Alerta'
print(tabla)
```

Como salida da:

```
   Color  Cambio
0   rojo  Alerta
1   rojo        
2  verde  Alerta
3  verde        
4   rojo  Alerta
5  verde  Alerta
6   rojo  Alerta
7  verde  Alerta
8   rojo  Alerta
```

Comment: Adecuado lo es y eficiente puede ser. Lo que haces es usar un filtro básico de pandas y mal no está :D

Comment: Gracias por la info @Christian

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte @TomyGijon!!!

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que tiene una confusión en el ciclo for in , en la variable i se está almacenando el string de cada elemento del array, NO es un iterador numérico, por lo que decir i+1, es incoherente, porque no está sumando a un iterador, y está mezclando string mas int , ese es el error que muestra.